# Which ship classes are depicted in the cover art for the Imperial Radch books?

Tags: object-identification, cover-art, imperial-radch

Which classes of ship are which in the art on the covers of the three books in the *Imperial Radch* series?

[image: All three book covers side by side showing a large big ship across them all and some smaller ships on each one individually]

[image]

Comment: +1 for the side-by-side presentation.  I hadn't realized all three covers were parts of the same artwork!

Comment: @Simon - I've added the un-typographed version (available here; https://www.orbitbooks.net/2013/07/01/cover-story-ancillary-justice-by-ann-leckie/)

Comment: Seems like artistic license. Big one may be a Justice, but small ones don't belong to 3 main classes IMO.

Comment: That means all the cover art was done in 2013, in time for the first book, which means it was done before Swords and Mercies were described.  So the background is likely intended as either a Justice or a station.

Comment: @DavidW - Or more likely just "*random ships against a background.*" which is John Harris' speciality as a cover designer

Comment: @Valorum I was trying to give the question the benefit of the doubt, but yes, that certainly is his style.  It's interesting to observe his transition from high-detail representational paintings, like Angus McKie's or Bob Layzell's 70's art, to a rougher, more abstract style over the years.

Comment: If they are meant to correspond to the three classes of ship mentioned in the book, it would  have to be that the big one is a Justice, the two red ones in the foreground are Swords and the smaller two on left are Mercys. I'm [not sure the scale is right](https://io9.gizmodo.com/get-to-know-the-incredible-starships-of-ann-leckies-anc-1733743808) for that though.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the large background ship is a Justice. Justice of Toren to be precise. The others are probably just shuttles, as Ann Leckie often mentions that shuttles are the ones that transport passengers from one ship to another, and from ship to station.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to back this up?

Comment: To back what up? I said "I believe" and "the others are probably just shuttles". I have no idea why I'm being downvoted for an answer like that. Anyway, this is my own conjecture, because the small starships kinda look like modern military planes. Additionally, there's this image from Orbit books showing different ship sizes: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/imperial-radch/images/b/b4/Ships.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170123153243

Comment: Around here, we're not looking for [wild mass guessing](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WildMassGuessing). The best answers have evidence to back up the assertions made.

Comment: You might want to consider going on the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and reading the [FAQ] before diving in and then complaining about your answers not meeting our standards. It's not gatekeeping to politely ask people to RTFM